# How to put the return of a function in a QLineEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt

I should add the return of the functions `result1` and `result2` in the boxes `text1` and `text2` of a Qt application, right when I click the relative button (mind that all the variables I'm using are global):

```
def result1(a, b):
    z = result2(a, c)
    return (a*b)/float(z)
def result2(a, c):
    return a/float(c)

button1.clicked.connect(setting)
button2.clicked.connect(setting)
def setting():
    if c != 0:
        text2.setText(result2(a, c))
        text1.setText(result1(a, b))
    return
```

Without focusing on the functions `result1` and `result2` (I didn't write them), we know that the returns are both float (I tried printing them).

When I'm setting the text of the boxes it displays me this error:

```
QLineEdit.setText(QString): argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
```

So I tried with the method `toString` like this:

```
def setting():
    if c != 0:
        text2.setText(result2(a, c).toString())
        text1.setText(result1(a, b).toString())
    return
```

But, now, there's another error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toString'
```

Why is the return of a function a `NoneType`?

Comment: The problem is not the line edit, it is that your functions returns `None`. Try to print their result, along with the arguments a,b and c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're sure the function is returning floats, which it sounds like it is whenever you're not trying to set it as the text in you QLineEdit, you should be able to just do something like:

```
def setting():
    if c != 0:
        text2.setText(str(result2(a, c)))
        text1.setText(str(result1(a, b)))
    return
```

of course, as you said, this requires that text2 and text1 are global.

Another option I've had some good success with is using a global variable as your value when you first create your QLineEdit:

```
global Result_T2
global Result_T1
Result_T2 = ""
Result_T1 = ""
text2.setText(Result_T2)
text1.setText(Result_T1)
.
.
.
def setting():
    if c != 0:
        Result_T2 = str(result2(a, c))
        Result_T1 = str(result1(a, b))
    return
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted the function you have in your edited question and it's working fine for me. Do you have an example of what you're plugging in for a and c that makes it break?

Comment: The first thing I see is that, with those inputs, you'll have a divide by zero in Result2. Your Result2 function will always have this error if `c = 0` but there are other combinations of inputs that will cause it, too.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
from random import choice as rand

def result2(a, b, c, d): 
    z = (1 + c/100.0)**(1.0/d) - 1
    w = (1 + z)**b
    return (a*z*w)/(w - 1)

def result1(a, b, d, e):
    x, y = 0.0, float(e)/a
    while y - x > 0.000001:
        j = (x + y)/2
        c = 100*((1 + j)**float(d) - 1)
        q = result2(a, b, c, d)
        x, y = (x, j) if q > c else (j, y)
    return 100*((1 + (x + y)/2)**float(d) - 1)

iterate = 1
while iterate<10:    
    a = rand(range(-10000,10000))
    temp = list(range(-10,10))
    temp.remove(0)
    b = rand(temp)
    c = rand(temp)
    d = rand(temp)
    e = rand(range(-3000,3000))

    print(result2(a,b,c,d))
    print(result1(a,b,d,e))    
    iterate += 1
```

You have to make sure you limit the combinations of variables that will cause a divide by zero. What I have here does not guarantee that, but it's very unlikely that a combination will arise to produce a divide by zero.